# How to Set directory path for multiple files with given extension in app.config in c#

Tags: c#

I am able to set path of a particular file  with a given filename in app.config using:

```
<add key="FilePath" value="\C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\abc.jpg"/>
```

but when I want to set path for "*.jpg" , i.e. for retrieving multiple filenames with jpg extension, i am facing problems in using wildcard character *.

how should I give the value in appsettings?

Thanx all !!!

Comment: Solved myself ! 
Instead of checking for file.exists ,  now I a m checking for directory.exists. Once directory  exists, I am reading filenames using Getfiles. 

Thanx all for inputs !!!

Answer (score 1):

When you read the value in, can't you just parse the wildcard and perform your multiple filename retrieval then?

```
<add key="FilePath" value="\C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\*.jpg"/>

string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"].ToString();
if(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path) == "*")
{
   //get multiple files
}
```

Comment: Tried this, but in quotes it takes *.jpg as a string only, thus loosing its wildcard character.
Dint work..

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean "in quotes it takes *.jpg as a string only"? Once you have the value of `FilePath`, you know exactly what the filename is (e.g `*`).

Answer (score 0):

in app.config file write

```
<add key="FilePath" value="\C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\"/>
```

in code

```
string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"].ToString() + filename;
```

Comment: In code it can only work when I already have the filename , which I don't.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two entries in the app.config.

```
1. FolderPath = <add key="FilePath" value="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\"/>
2. FileType =  <add key="FileType" value="*.jpg"/>
```

Read the values from app.config

```
    string folderPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"].ToString();
    string type = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileType"].ToString();
```

Get the files:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, type);
```

Or
Single entry in app.config

```
<add key="FilePath" value="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\*.jpg"/>
```

Get files.

```
string folderPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"].ToString();
var dirName = Path.GetDirectoryName(folderPath);
var fileType = Path.GetFileName(folderPath);
var files = Directory.GetFiles(dirName, fileType);
```